# Should we automatically test spring contexts using TDD?

Tags: spring, testing, spring-mvc, tdd

I'm using TDD on a personal project.

Since I shouldn't write anything (code, XML config, SQL, whatever) without a failing test, I was wondering what kind of "unit" test (it's probably more of an integration test) I could write if I want to setup spring MVC.

Lets say that I *want* to write something like that in a spring-context.xml file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Can you add a test for "context:component-scan" ?

And what should you /can you test on the bean "viewResolver"?

Here's a bit of code I wrote for the tests :

```
package com.abc.test.integration;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:web/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml" })
public class SpringServletContextConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void TestControllerContextConfigurationIsNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void TestViewBeanResolverExists() {
        assertEquals(true, applicationContext.containsBean("viewResolver"));
    }

}
```

Is there anything else I could test about this "setup" ?

Comment: Are you testing the framework, or your own code?  Because if you're essentially testing the framework, I think your time would be better spent coming up with tests that represent your application logic.

Comment: I agree with you Robert. I guess it could be argued that he is testing his configuration code and the configured state of his application, in which case the test (as he has written) would be that all the appropriate spring beans are setup correctly. Counter to that would be that if the beans aren't setup correctly your app is going to fail pretty quickly, which would be revealed by a smoke test.

Comment: It depends, spring configuration can get really "heavy".  Anyway, I was trying to do that because I heard at a conference that when using TDD, you shouldn't code anything before you write a test that fails (including XML, SQL, configurations, etc.)

Comment: @digitaljoel Lets say that you have a transaction setup on some part of the application and somebody just mess with it. It could be hard to find in a smoke test, no?

Comment: @mrmuggles "(including XML, SQL, configurations, etc.)" : where did you hear that ? It seems a bit extreme and hardly feasible. Besides, TDD is mainly about unit tests, not integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

Please, whenever you hear someone say:

> "Never write **any** production code without a failing test"

Either *ignore* them or do what I do, imagine they (correctly) said:

> "Never write any **domain logic** without a failing test".

Please don't worry about your Spring configuration. If you've got it wrong, guess what? Your app won't work when you try to use it. If this happens, you'll simply make the fix and move on. No test in the world will save you here. You've tagged this question about TDD. Here's a secret, TDD has *very little to with testing*. The fact you get a suite of automated tests to catch regressions is a bonus. TDD is more a design process than anything else. No matter how much you automate, **manual testing is still required**.

If you have a few end to end tests, which just act as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing), you will notice as soon as you break the Spring configuration anyway. Simply diff your source control and you will immediately see what you have changed.